# SVN: Would there be any problems having a branch for each customer?

Tags: svn, branching-and-merging

We have a custom made CMS and many clients who want a site built with it. The solution structure is something like this:

```
Libs
- Lib1
- Lib2
- etc
Plugins
- Plugin1
- Plugin2
- etc
MVC Web Project
```

The MVC Web project holds the admin theme, the layout and assets for site, etc... most of what's in there will be the same for every customer - only a few files will change (mostly theme related stuff, config files and the like). It would be a waste and a nightmare for maintenance if we had to make a copy of the project each and every time to put into different SVN repositories.

I have never worked with SVN branching and merging before, but I understand the concept. What I am thinking of doing though may be somewhat strange... let me explain:

I noted that SVN creates "cheap copy" branches - so it doesn't make copies of every single file. I am thinking of doing something like this:

```
trunk
- code for main project
branches
- Customer1's Project
- Customer2's Project
- then some real dev branches of course
tags
- Version 1 (Generic Demo Project)
- Version 2 (Generic Demo Project)
- etc
```

My idea is to have a branch for each customer where only those few files are changed and I am HOPING that it will be easy to merge the latest code from the trunk to each of the customer branches when there are changes.

I am guessing this is not normal, but is it viable? Does anyone see any potential problems with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My idea is to have a branch for each customer

I've seen this happen in many companies.

I've *never* seen a single company who was glad they did it.

---

Consider this... What happens when you get more customers?  The complexity of maintaining the codebase grows *exponentially*.  Any time you make a change, you have to merge it out that many more times.  Any time you fix a bug, you have to re-merge and re-test that many more times.  And you have to manually keep track of which changes have been promoted to which customer branches.  And it's going to be *very*, ***very*** tempting/easy to do a "quick hot fix" for a specific customer because they're complaining loudly about it and then almost immediately forget about it.

And what about testing?  Is QA prepared to re-test each branch individually?  Because that's exactly where this leads.  (The alternative is to test one branch, merge to another, and assume it works.  It's generally not a good idea to ship a different codebase than the one that was tested.)

This mess gets big *fast*.

---

> I noted that SVN creates "cheap copy" branches - so it doesn't make copies of every single file.

Ignore that fact during this consideration.  Disk space isn't expensive.  If you're increasing maintenance complexity just to save a few bytes of disk space then, at a business level, the decision you're making reflects that the business and its employees' time are less valuable than a hard drive.  That's a pretty bad place for a business to be.

---

> most of what's in there will be the same for every customer - only a few files will change (mostly theme related stuff, config files and the like)

Excellent.  Then a big step toward being able to manage this would be to define *exactly* what's customer-specific and separate it from what isn't.  In an ideal world the customer-specific stuff (also thought of as environment-specific or deployment-specific) can be defined in a single configuration file.  It *could* be more complex than that, but that's the goal you're aiming at.

You definitely want to avoid customer-specific *code*.  The same codebase should satisfy every customer and customizations should be defined outside of that codebase.  That way the one single codebase can be tested and validated.

Customer-specific configurations can be stored in source control, often parallel to the codebase and included as part of a build/deploy scenario.  There's no need for branches there, each customer can just have their own folder in some customizations folder.  Adding a new customer is then simply a matter of adding a new configuration folder and, at worst, a new case statement to a build/deploy script to grab from that folder when preparing/packaging the system for shipping.

---

Branches are used (all too often overused in my opinion) to deviate from the codebase, not from the deployment target.  (Though some systems do have things like a "dev" branch and a "prod" branch.  Those are technically deployment targets.  That's really used as an explicit snapshotting mechanism, not really as a branching mechanism.)

Comment: Very nice answer, thanks for you time. The only thing I am wondering about is if I do in fact need to make minor code changes; something specific to a customer. For example, we have something called a PageType, which we would like each customer to be able to create their own page types. However, we obviously don't want any custom page types showing up in every other customer's CMS... and as stated, we'd not like to create a new repo just for a small change like that. Do you have any advice for such a scenario?

Comment: In case you were wondering... the page types are in fact defined in code - not in the backend. Thus, the problem...

Comment: @Matt: Not being familiar with the architecture of what you're building, my inclination is still to keep the codebase all-inclusive and make changes a matter of configuration.  However, I recognize that there *are* cases where custom logic is needed.  (Making that configurable often means making a "rules engine", and if you thought things were complex now...)  In that case, can this code customization be kept in a separate module?  Individual modules could be individually tested/validated, kept with the customizations, and injected at build/deploy time.

Comment: Yes, this is good.. I just put some customized code into a separate assembly (as a plugin)... I can drop customized code in for each customer as a plugin... brilliant. Thanks for the great response.